# Haskell / GHC: Unsafely deconstruct a constructor?

Tags: performance, haskell

Here's a specific case of the general question I'm really asking: Suppose I'm in a performance critical section of code and I've received a value

```
x :: Maybe Int
```

I know it's a `Just Int` and not a `Nothing`, but due to code out of my control, I can't arrange to receive the actual `Int` directly. I want to do

```
case x of
    Just i -> whatever i
```

but I don't want GHC to insert any checking or error handling or jumps or anything; just interpret the bits as if they are of the form `Just i` and let me deal with the consequences.

Is this possible? (Yes, I know this is something one shouldn't do regularly.)

Comment: Maybe playing some ugly tricks with `unsafeCoerce` and under a big assumption on how GHC precisely implements its runtime you can achieve this. But... I really doubt this check is a big problem: do you have any evidence for it? As Knuth puts it, premature optimization is the root of all evil. And don't use `unsafe*` stuff unless you really, really can not do without.

Comment: No, I don't have any evidence, and I will do some benchmarking before I implement anything.

Comment: Have you looked at the compiled Core that your program is generating? Depending on why a `Maybe` is involved in the first place, it's *possible* that GHC might have already removed it for you...

Comment: I have looked at the compiled Core. The situation is actually more complicated than I described here, involving a GADT, rather than `Maybe`. In my situation, it's actually in theory possible to tell by the type which constructors need to be matched on; the Core sometimes uses this information well and sometimes does not (and thus includes an error case that can't happen). I think I can work with that, though.

Comment: Heed @chi's advise. You rarely will guess correctly what are the performance problems in your program even in imperative straightforward languages.  In Haskell... well let's say that GHC  it is a creatively wild compiler for adrenaline addicted freaks, the sort that would practice [paragliding in the fiords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrklTR4buEc) if they were into that kind of things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can help GHC figure out that a GADT pattern match is total by adding some pattern signatures. I'm not really sure why that sometimes helps but it can. If you really want unsafe, the way to do it is to make a more informative GADT than the one you are working with and unsafely coerce to it. Something like this:

```
data Shmaybe :: Bool -> * -> * where
  Noway :: Shmaybe r a
  Shucks :: a -> Shmaybe True a

fromShucks :: ShMaybe True a -> a
fromShucks (Shucks a) = a

unsafeFromJust :: forall a . Maybe a -> a
unsafeFromJust m = fromShucks (unsafeCoerce m :: Shmaybe True a)
```

It's important that the constructors match in both argument types and order. Obviously, this is all absurdly unsafe and comes with no guarantees. Segmentation faults may happen.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `YOLO` typeclass
https://gist.github.com/nkpart/8922083d3c18a8f777b8

```
instance Yolo Maybe where
  yolo (Just x) = x
```

N.B: That was a joke. Use `fromJust`.

Comment: `fromJust` includes a check for `Nothing`, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Then maybe use `Yolo`

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of several possibilities, but all implicitly include code for
throwing errors in the `Nothing` case.

*Irrefutable pattern*:

```
λ> let Just a = Just "hi"
λ> a
"hi"
λ> let Just a = Nothing
λ> a
*** Exception: <interactive>:4:5-20: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Data.Maybe.Just a
```

*Non-exhastive patterns*:

```
λ> let f (Just a) = a
λ> f (Just "hi")
"hi"
λ> f Nothing
*** Exception: <interactive>:6:5-18: Non-exhaustive patterns in function f
```

`fromJust` (check and throw error):

```
λ> fromJust (Just "hi")
"hi"
λ> fromJust Nothing
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

You cannot use `unsafeCoerce` because for all `a` the internal representations of `Maybe a` and `a` are different, and I am
not aware of a way to tell GHC to not check the other cases in
an irrefutable pattern.

Have you shown that this behaviour has
undesirable performance characteristics and that there aren't
other, easier optimisations?  Unless you have, I would not worry about
it :)